# How i can use email verification with this code

Tags: php, email, verification

```
<?php
      require 'config.php';

      $success=FALSE;

      if(!empty($_POST))
      {
         $username = $_POST['username'];
         $username = strip_tags($username);

         $password = $_POST['password'];
         $password = strip_tags($password); 
         $password = md5($password);

         $email = $_POST['email'];
         $email = strip_tags($email);

         $name = $_POST['name'];
         $name = strip_tags($name);

         $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";//username check
         $esql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";     //email check
         $eqry=mysql_query($esql);                            // email made query
         $qry=mysql_query($sql);                             //username made query
         $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qry); 
         $enum_rows= mysql_num_rows($eqry);
         if($num_rows>0 )
         {
             echo 'Username already taken';
         }
         else if ($enum_rows>0)
         {
             echo 'email already registered';
         }
         else
         {
             $success=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,name) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email','$name')");
         }

         if($success)
         {
             header('Location:regthank.html');
         }

      }
?>
```

Comment: Can I have [Robert'); DROP TABLE users;--](http://bobby-tables.com) as a username?

Comment: and also look into SQL Injection as mentioned by @TheBlueDog

Comment: Migrating your code to a non-deprecated MySQL connector that supports prepared statements such as mysqli or PDO would be a good start. Once you've secured you code, then you can consider email verification. You are currently not only putting the security of your own database at risk, but also the security of your users. Finally, md5 hashing of passwords is not acceptable by any stretch of the imagination.

Answer (score 1):

after

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$email = strip_tags($email);
```

you can do a check like this

```
$is_valid_email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

this will return `true` or `false`.

then just make sure this part does not get executed if `$is_valid_email` is `false`:

```
} else {
   $success=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,name) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email','$name')");
}
```

Comment: Hi, actually , i looking for howi can send activation code by email to user and they will input the code (no url link) and it will check the code with databse and it will verify user , how i can do that

Comment: oh wow...that's what you meant. That's a whole bunch of questions rolled into one. You have a long way ahead of you. To get started, look into the php `mail()` [function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp) to send the activation code.

Comment: He's got a whole bunch of other issues to sort out before he even considers email verification.

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = "Your Activation Code is ".$code."";
$to=$email;
$subject="Activation Code For Talkerscode.com";
$from = 'your email';
$body='Your Activation Code is '.$code.' Please Click On This link <a href="verification.php">Verify.php?id='.$db_id.'&code='.$code.'</a>to activate your account.';
$headers = "From:".$from;
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);

echo "An Activation Code Is Sent To You Check You Emails";
```

insert this code to send email to user to confirm the email address for complete tutorial http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/account-verification-system-through-email-using-php.php